# GSM shiled and Ethernet shild compatibility

Tags: arduino, conflict, gsm, ethernet

I have an Arduino Uno Rev. 3 and have bought a [GSM Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield)
and an [Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield). 
If I use the Arduino and GSM shield or the ethernet shield all works well.  However, I want to use the Arduino with both the GSM shield and the ethernet shield.

I have searched the Internet and have read that I have a conflict on pin 4. The GSM shield uses pin 4 for the SD Card and the ethernet shield uses pin 4 for TX.

Can i fix this error? Is it possible to change this pin.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Yeah, it depends whether the problem can be fixed in software or whether the solution is to modify the hardware.  It would probably be better asked on the [Arduino SE site](http://arduino.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have had a look at the specifications for the two shields that you provided links for and there doesn't appear to be a pin conflict.  The GSM shield uses pins 2,3 & 7 while the Ethernet shield uses pins 4, 10, 11, 12 & 13. The GSM shield doesn't have an SD card reader but there is one the Ethernet shield.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a shield, hardware is managed in such a way that it will always connect to the particular pins. you can understood this in this way that if you place your Ethernet shield upon the Arduino then Ethernet's Tx pin will always connect to Arduino's pin 4.

So there is only one method to overcome this problem, don't place Ethernet shield directly to Ardunio. connect this with the jumpers externally and change Tx pin 4 to another pin in the programming which is free.

I don't know which pins are free in your code but lets assume Arduino's pin 6 is free so declare this as Ethernet TX pin (you will find out this in program) and connect this to Ethernet's pin 4.

You can use only one shield directly, now choose which one you want to use directly and change the pin configuration for the shield which is used externally.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but i don't know how to change the pin 4 in the ethernet library, can you help me? i see this [library](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Ethernet) but i don't know which file edit for fix it. help me please !!!

Comment: I go through the link of GSM shield and Ethernet Shield as you show it above in your question and I find out some things e.g. 1st one is that pins 10, 11, 12, and 13 for Ethernet and pin 4 for selecting SD card on Ethernet shield. 2nd one is that pins 2 and 3 for software serial communication on GSM shield.
So my question is why are you getting worry man here is no confliction.

Comment: hi i fix the problem, i have a link from pin 2 abd pin 10, but this i a bad for arduino uno rev.3